# In Scala what's a functional way to check that an array is monotonic?

Tags: scala

I have an array `val x : Array[Double]` and would like to check as precondition to a function that every `x(i) <= x(i+1)` for all `i`. What's the way to do it using functional programming in Scala. I looked for e.g. `foldLeft` or `foldRight` but they accumulate rather than visiting every pair of adjacent elements.

Comment: In Haskell, you'd `zip` a list with itself so that you get pairs of adjacent elements. Not sure if it's as elegant in Scala.

Comment: Why plain old "def isMonotonic(...)" with while loop inside is "unelegant"? One don't have to use those inefficient zips/sliding to be "functional". As long as your function is pure, it is OK. Practicality should be the goal, not "elegance".

Comment: OK removed the elegant word .. I was interested in the functional form solution. The reason why functional is elegant to me is a personal thing perhaps but I guess has to do with better communication of intent = elegance

Comment: @Bergi `(vs, vs.view.drop(1)).zipped.forall(_ < _)`. The view just manages indexes, and `zipped` doesn't build anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
def isMonotonic(arr:Array[Int]) = 
   if (arr.isEmpty) true
   else (arr, arr.tail).zipped.forall {case (a,b) => a <= b}
```

Simplified solution (thanks to @som-snytt):

```
def isMonotonic(arr:Array[Int]) = 
   (arr, arr.drop(1)).zipped.forall (_ <= _)
```

Comment: Avoid intermediate collections: `(vs, vs.view.drop(1)).zipped.forall(_ < _)`.

Comment: Is vs.view.drop(1) equivalent to vs.view.tail? I would prefer the second one

Comment: Then solution became even more simple, thanks @som-snytt!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`IterableLike.sliding`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.IterableLike@sliding(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]):

```
val isMonotonic = 
  Seq(1,2,3,4,5).sliding(2).forall {
    case Seq(x, y) => x < y
    case _ => true
  }
```

### Edit:

Since you're using an `Array[Double]`, you'll need:

```
val isMonotonic = 
  Array(1d, 2d, 3d, 4d, 5d).sliding(2).forall {
    case Array(x, y) => x < y
    case _ => true
  }
```

Comment: Maybe rather `case x::y::_`?

Comment: @Bergi Definitely, much more elegant.

Comment: `::_` ?  How would that happen?

Comment: @jwvh It would just ignore the tail of the list if it exists, wouldn't it? I see it working in the REPL.

Comment: But that's my question.  How could there be any tail?  How could there be anything to ignore?

Comment: Nice solution, but you have to process case when Set contains less than 2 items

Comment: @jwvh It ignores the empty list. I guess one could equally have written `case List(x, y)`

Comment: @Bergi, my point exactly.  I think your `List()` suggestion is cleaner and easier to read/understand.

Comment: @jwvh Added it as an additional solution.

Comment: @Nyavro In that case, the iterator doesn't contain any elements (if I interpret [the docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.IterableLike) correctly) and `forAll` would yield `true`

Comment: The problem is in match statement. You should add case _. Try to run on Seq(1)

Comment: @Bergi He's right. In case the sequence has a single element it blows on the match.

Comment: When I plugin my `val x: Array[Double]` I get the following error `constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : scala.collection.immutable.::[B] required: Array[Double]`

Comment: @GiovanniAzua I've added a case for arrays.

Comment: @som-snytt Can you elaborate why using array extractor is bad?

Comment: @som-snytt I tested it in the REPL.

Comment: @som-snytt [No, I don't.](https://gist.github.com/YuvalItzchakov/8922636e2fa8b5b0e060fb6f69adbd0e). This is running Scala 2.11.8

Comment: @som-snytt I also see [other examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647166/how-do-i-pattern-match-arrays-in-scala) doing exactly that same?

Answer (score 1):

With a couple of fine answers to choose from, the next question is: Can we make it generic?

This is my shot at it.

```
def isMonotonic[T](ts: Traversable[T])(implicit ev: Ordering[T]): Boolean = {
  if (ts.size < 2) true
  else if (ev.gt(ts.head, ts.tail.head)) false
  else isMonotonic(ts.tail)
}
```

Appears to work for the following.

```
isMonotonic(Array('c','a','z'))             // false
isMonotonic(Vector(3.1, 2.2, 7.7))          // false
isMonotonic(List[Int]())                    // true
isMonotonic(Seq("abc", "bcb", "tz", "xs"))  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach

```
def isMonotonic(xs:List[Int]) = xs.sliding(2)
                                  .collectFirst{case List(x,y) if x > y => 1}
                                  .isEmpty
```

Works on empty and length-one lists because the partial function  is never defined on those. Because it's `collectFirst`, it bails at the first evidence it's not monotonic The `xs zip xs.drop(1)` idea can be used if preferred